# 5-V CPLD family in-circuit programmability

Tags: 5v, jtag, programmable-logic

I have a need for a relatively small amount of 5V-logic (active at power-up) that would perfectly fit a package like that of the [ATF750CL CPLD from Atmel/Microchip](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATF750CL), the [DigiKey page](https://www.digikey.com/short/zmnj4c) for these devices lists them as "In-System programmable" yet, try as I might, I don't seem to find any information on designing the JTAG programming interface for them (I looked through all of the documentation I have been able to find).

A missing feature is something that clearly does not make the datasheet. The smaller [ATF16V8B](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATF16V8B) would also work, save for that in-circuit programmability issue.
Is this just a mistake on Digikey's part? (I already reported it to them). Am I really stuck with much larger devices like the [ATF15xxx](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8968-CPLD-ATF-ISP-User%20Guide.pdf) or their equivalents from other vendors? (I do need 5V-functionality).